# WORKDAY.INTL function not working correctly

Tags: workday-api

I am trying to get past dates using WORKDAY.INTL. For example i need to create a shipping plan and the company only ships on certain days. i.e. `Monday/Wednesday/Friday`. Here is an example below:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL("1/07/2019",-5,"0101011")
```

The result should be `24/06/2019`, however, my formula is returning `18/06/2019`.

Can you please help?

Comment: I think you have the wrong tag.  You probably want `VBA`

Comment: Also, that isn't how the function works.  You can only exclude two days and they have to be consecutive.  You probably need to write a UDF.